# the max number of an occurence in R

Tags: r

I have this array:

```
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  [25]  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  [49]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  [73]  1  1  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  3  2  3  3  2  3  2  3  2  3  3  2  3  3  2
  [97]  3  2  2  2  3  2  2  2  2  2  3  2  3  3  2  3  2  1  2  2  3  2  2  3
```

I need a function that returns only the number of the maximum occurrences. For example, if I use:

```
table(x[1:80])
```

I will get:

```
 1  2  3  4 
74  3  2  1
```

How can I get automatically the value '74'? Meaning that I can't know if '1' or '2' and so on... is the the maximum occurrence in my array. Thanks!

Edit:

I run:

```
tf<- tablulate(x):

[1] 75 24 19  1  1
```

and tried to run a `for` loop to get the "maximum" of each element on the "tabulate result" as following:

```
for (element in tf)
{
+ b= max(table(x[element]))
+ print (b)
+ }
```

I don't get the expected result, it is probably simple but not really for me.
I tried this:

```
> a=max(table(C[1:75]))
[1] 72
> b=max(table(C[76:99]))
[1] 11
> c=max(table(C[100:118]))
[1] 12
> d=max(table(C[119]))
[1] 1
> e=max(table(C[120]))
[1] 1
```

and so on.
and it works but it's really long and not fun if I have a big dataset.

Comment: You can wrap it with `max` `max(table(x[1:80]))` (if I understand it correctly)

Comment: or `sort(table(x), decreasing=T)[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the commenter's tip, if you want a function use:

```
maximum <- function(vector, upto=length(vector)) {
  max(table(vector[1:upto]))
}
```

So for:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1:3, 100, replace=T)
maximum(x)
[1] 34

maximum(x, 55) #checking at the 55th number in the vector
[1] 19
```

## Update

To answer your edited question. Use this function:

```
maxtable <- function(vector) {
  index <- cumsum(1:length(vector) %in% cumsum(tabulate(vector)))
  s <- split(vector, index)
  sapply(s, function(v) max(table(v)))
}

maxtable(x)
 0  1  2  3  4  5 
71 11 12  1  1  1
```

## Edit

I think this small change is more of what you're looking for:

```
maxtable2 <- function(vector) {
  index <- cumsum(1:length(vector) %in% (cumsum(tabulate(vector))+1))
  s <- split(vector, index+1)
  sapply(s, function(v) max(table(v)))
}
maxtable2(x)
 1  2  3  4  5 
72 11 12  1  1
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I edited my question, could you check it with me please?

Comment: @yokie do you want to be able to enter a range of values into the function? Like this? `maximum(x, 11:20)` to get the max occurrence only in that section?

Comment: the "maximum" of each occurence in the "tabulate function result" if you consider my last example

Comment: show the desired result, not just the wrong one so I know what you're talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78418/discussion-between-plafort-and-yokie).

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in the library `modeest` that gets you most of the way there called `mfv`. But the function itself is simple enough to make yourself:

```
> mfv
function (x, ...) 
{
    f <- factor(x)
    tf <- tabulate(f)
    return(as.numeric(levels(f)[tf == max(tf)]))
}
<environment: namespace:modeest>
```

So you can do `sum(x == mfv(x))` to get 74.